# Expression tree (infix to prefix)

Tags: expression-trees

Q create expression tree infix to prefix

1 - * + A B C / D E
2 + - + A * B C D / E F

not getting the expression tree ( prefix, postfix) concept ! I don't need code I want concept!

Request: Also tell me the easiest way to construct the expression trees infix to prefix, also                 infix to postfix from the complex notations (i.e. it is parenthesized or we have to make it parenthesized)  with examples and its explanation in complete steps!